# Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, html

I am getting this error message on an assignment for class. Ive created an UPDATE which uses forms for a user to edit the content being printed out from a database on the previous page.

I am getting  Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens on line 14

```
<?
require '../connection.php';
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {    
    $sql = "UPDATE videoinfo
            SET submitter = :submitter,
                videoTitle = :videoTitle,
                channelName = :channelName,
                videoLink = :videoLink
            WHERE videoId = :videoId";
    $stmt = $dataconn -> prepare($sql);
    $stmt -> execute( array(":submitter" => $_POST['submitter'],
                            ":videoTitle" => $_POST['videoTitle'],
                            ":channelName" => $_POST['channelName'],
                            ":videoLink" => $_POST['videoLink']) ); 

    echo "Record Updated";
    echo "<br />";
    include 'adminmain.php';
} else { 
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM videoinfo AS v
        WHERE videoId = :videoId";      
$stmt = $dataconn -> prepare($sql);
$stmt -> execute( array(":videoId" => $_POST['videoId']) );
$video = $stmt->fetch();
}?>

<html>
<?
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
?>

  <form method="post">
      Submitter: <input type="text" name="submitter" value="<?= $video['submitter'] ?>" /> <br />
      Video Title: <input type="text" name="videoTitle" value="<?= $video['videoTitle'] ?>" /> <br />
      Channel Name: <input type="text" name="channelName" value="<?= $video['channelName'] ?>" /> <br />
      Video Link: <input type="text" name="videoLink" value="<?= $video['videoLink'] ?>" /> <br />
      <input type="hidden" name="videoId" value="<?= $video['videoId'] ?>" />
      <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save" />  
  </form>

<?
  }//endIf
?>
</html>
```

Comment: Might be unrelated, but this could be a contributing factor `AS v` --- Usually when using a column alias, the echo'ed column looks like `$row['v']` as an example. Try removing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have five bound parameters but are only binding four values to them. You're missing your value for `:videoId`.

```
$sql = "UPDATE videoinfo
        SET submitter = :submitter,
            videoTitle = :videoTitle,
            channelName = :channelName,
            videoLink = :videoLink
        WHERE videoId = :videoId";
$stmt = $dataconn -> prepare($sql);
$stmt -> execute( array(":submitter" => $_POST['submitter'],
                        ":videoTitle" => $_POST['videoTitle'],
                        ":channelName" => $_POST['channelName'],
                        ":videoLink" => $_POST['videoLink'],
                        ":videoId" => $_POST['videoId']
                        ) 
                );
```

Comment: This fixed that but now when it returns to adminmain.php it gives me the error "Notice: Undefined variable: videoId in /home/CLASSES/auxiercolint/CST336/final_project/update.php on line 15"

And doesnt actually update the database.

Comment: I was skeptical about that missing variable at first, but figured the OP was using it via the SELECT passed via the hidden field. As per [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418847/invalid-parameter-number-number-of-bound-variables-does-not-match-number-of-tok#comment35888015_23418847) about the `AS v`

Comment: @user3594605 I made up that variable based on pure speculation about what it might be named. You should now what the variable containing the video ID is and replace it with the one I provided.

Comment: John, this `":videoId" => $videoId` should be `":videoId" => $_POST['videoId']`, right?

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's probably what it is. I should update my answer with that as it is a best of a guess as it gets. (If that is even close to proper English).

Comment: Thanks @JohnConde this fixed this issue. I have one more but I think it warrants a separate post made for it.

Comment: Works for me John ;-)

Comment: Plus, OP isn't bothering much on reading comments posted under his question(s). New one just popped up, wondering if he'll see [`that`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23419051/youtube-embed-code-stored-in-database-not-appearing-in-html-form#comment35888535_23419051). http://stackoverflow.com/q/23419051/ I wonder sometimes why I even bother (lol)

Comment: That happens a lot which has caused a lot of discussion in Meta about question quality.

Comment: Well, I managed to solve OP's other problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/23420722/ had to setup a DB for it lol oh well, didn't take me long. 5 mins. but then the question got closed a few hours ago. I managed to slip my answer in.