# PHP MYSQL INSERT help no errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im attempting to piggy back on my Add a video submission form to update another mysql table to keep track of what submitter posts what video links. Im trying to insert the video ID by taking the last videoId inserted into the submission table using MAX() and the username will just be taken from :submitter and the postedOn is using now() to get a timestamp. After using the submission form no data is entered into the adminposts table and im not getting any errors. Thanks for the help.

```
<?php


    require_once '../connection.php';

    $sql = "INSERT INTO videoinfo
            (submitter,videoTitle,channelName,videoLink,videoLength)
            VALUES(:submitter,:videoTitle,:channelName,:videoLink,:videoLength)";

    $stmt = $dataconn -> prepare($sql); 
    $stmt -> execute(array(":submitter"=> $_POST['submitter'],
    ":videoTitle"=> $_POST['videoTitle'],
    ":channelName"=> $_POST['channelName'],
    ":videoLink"=> $_POST['videoLink'],
    ":videoLength"=> $_POST['videoLength']));

    $sql = "SELECT MAX(videoId) FROM videoinfo";
    $stmt = $dataconn->prepare($sql);   
    $stmt -> execute(array());
    $record = $stmt->fetch();
    $videoID = $record['videoId'];

    $username = $_POST['submitter'];
    $postedOn = now();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO adminposts
            (videoId,username,postedOn)
            VALUES(:videoId,:username,postedOn = now())";
    $stmt = $dataconn -> prepare($sql);
    $stmt -> execute(array(":videoId"=> $videoID,
                            ":username"=> $username));      





    echo "<h3>Video has been successfully added!";

    include 'adminmain.php'
    ?>
```

updated Code

```
    $sql = "SELECT MAX(videoId) AS videoId FROM videoinfo";
    $stmt = $dataconn->prepare($sql);   
    $stmt -> execute(array());
    $record = $stmt->fetch();
    $videoID = $record['videoId'];
    var_dump($videoID);
    $username = $_POST['submitter'];
    $postedOn = now();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO adminposts
            (videoId,username,postedOn)
            VALUES(:videoId,:username,$postedOn)";
    $stmt = $dataconn -> prepare($sql);
    $stmt -> execute(array(":videoId"=> $videoID,
                            ":username"=> $username));
$stmt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: How do you know you're not getting any errors? There's not one single check anywhere in your code. Do some error checking.

Comment: 2nd query needs an alias since `max(col_name)` will return as `max(col_name)` in the result set so use as `SELECT MAX(videoId) as videoId`

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php <= right there.

Comment: `$postedOn = now();` and `postedOn = now()` (`VALUES(:videoId,:username,postedOn = now())";`) what's wrong with this picture?

Comment: I suggest you `var_dump($videoID);` right after `$videoID = $record['videoId'];` and see if you're getting anything from it. Has the answer below helped at all? @runboyrun

Comment: @Fred-ii- still no luck. I tried the PDO check and its still showing no errors?

Comment: What result did you get with `var_dump($videoID);`?

Comment: @Fred-ii- still the same results. It adds the submission only and doesnt insert the info for the adminposts table.

Comment: I know that, but is there a string that comes up? I need to "see" what the var_dump spit out. Plus you'll need to change `VALUES(:videoId,:username,postedOn)";` to `VALUES(:videoId,:username,$postedOn)";` you left out the `$` for `postedOn` I just noticed that now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the vardump doesnt spit out anything. Okay changed.

Comment: I'm starting to question your first execute `$stmt -> execute(array());` since there isn't an actual array of data to be processed, can you try just a plain ol `$stmt -> execute();` wait.. hold that thought.

Comment: Instead of `$record = $stmt->fetch();` try `$record = $stmt->fetchColumn();`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Nothing is still going into the table. Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

I have to point out that you can't use `$postedOn = now();` as a variable to post the current time/date. It needs to be entered as part of the `VALUES`

I.e.: `VALUES(:videoId,:username,NOW())";`

Do note that I used `$pdo` as the connection variable.

```
<?php

$mysql_hostname = 'xxx';
$mysql_username = 'xxx';
$mysql_password = 'xxx';
$mysql_dbname = 'xxx';

try {

$pdo= new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password); 
     $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
     exit( $e->getMessage() );
}

$sql = "SELECT MAX(videoId) AS videoId FROM videoinfo";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);   
$stmt -> execute(array());
$record = $stmt->fetch();
$videoID = $record['videoId'];

// var_dump($videoID);

$username = $_POST['submitter'];

try {
$sql = "INSERT INTO adminposts
        (videoId,username,postedOn)
        VALUES(:videoId,:username,NOW())";
$stmt = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
$stmt -> execute(array(":videoId"=> $videoID,":username"=> $username));
}

catch(PDOException $e){
// $result = "Sorry, an error occurred while editing the database.";

// will print a message of the actual error should there be one
print $e->getMessage();

    }
```

Comment: Huzza! success. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You're very much welcome, glad I could help. Was a fun project to work on. Cheers @runboyrun

Comment: Talk about going the extra mile. Also, talk about staying up late. :/

Comment: When I feel I can fix it and make a difference in someone's day (*night in my case lol*), yes I like going the "extra mile". I'm somewhat of a night owl, but I did end up falling asleep right away lol @JohnConde

Answer (score 1):

As the comments to your question have highlighted, you do not perform any error-checking, and you will need to create an alias for MAX(videoId) if you wish to go that route.

However, for your specific use case, I'd suggest looking at PDO::lastInsertId() to get the videoId that you just inserted. http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

This will remove the need to explicitly write out a second query, and alias the MAX() column.