# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens oop

Tags: php, parameters

Here there, I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

when trying to run my PHP code. I am writing a oop database class.

Here is where my error is coming from:
pastebin:http://pastebin.com/12vLTZPZ

Comment: Run your query in phpmyadmin. Field & Values count are not same.

Comment: fixed... didnt pass in an array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418847/invalid-parameter-number-number-of-bound-variables-does-not-match-number-of-tok)